# Javascript object is a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, object

I want to create an Object in a new JS file from another JS file.
I get the following error, `Object is not a function`, in the new file:

```
var Bricklet = require('../Bricklet');
var b = new Bricklet("afea", "sdafdf", "affe");
console.log(b);
```

When I try to create an object in the JS file itself it works.
Here is the code:

```
var Bricklet = (function () {
    function Bricklet(uid, deviceIdentifier, connectedUid) {
        this._uid = uid;
        this._deviceIdentifier = deviceIdentifier;
        this._connectedUid = connectedUid;
    }
    return Bricklet;
})();

var bricklet = new Bricklet("afea", "sdafdf", "affe");
console.log(bricklet);
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: What does your export look like? And I guess the error appears on line 2 (`new Bricklet(...)`), can you confirm?

Comment: You cannot import JavaScript files inside other JavaScript files. If this is a Node.js question, tag it as so, because this will not work in plain JavaScript.

Comment: You need to export `Bricklet` like: `module.exports = Bricklet`.

Comment: It depends what environment you're using (NodeJS, AMD in Browser, etc), but you haven't exported `Bricklet` anywhere, e.g. `define("Bricklet", [], function() {  /* ... */ return Bricklet });`

Comment: That's because your module doesn't _export_ the constructor. By default an object is exported which can't be used as constructor.

Comment: Is it in NodeJS then? If so, please add the tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the Bricklet function:

```
var Bricklet = (function () {
    function Bricklet(uid, deviceIdentifier, connectedUid) {
        this._uid = uid;
        this._deviceIdentifier = deviceIdentifier;
        this._connectedUid = connectedUid;
    }
    return Bricklet;
})();

var bricklet = new Bricklet("afea", "sdafdf", "affe");
console.log(bricklet);

module.exports = Bricklet; // <<------- Add this
```